# Basic upstart script to execute node.js script?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, upstart

I'm trying to write a very basic upstart script that runs a node.js script when I enter 'service myscript start'.

Upstart:

```
description "my script"
author "barbra"
setuid ubuntu
env NODE=/usr/bin/nodejs
env NODE_PATH=/root/

script
cd $NODE_PATH
$NODE app.js
end script
```

However upstart isn't recognizing this as a service and generating this error:

```
"Unit myscript.service not found"
```

Am I missing anything in my upstart script?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to check my upstart version using 'initctl version' and it replies:

```
"initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused"
```

Comment: FWIW upstart is gone by default in recent versions of Ubuntu, CentOS, and other distros that used to use it. The way I typically handle the differences in init systems is to install monit (using an init system-specific startup script one time for monit) and set up all of the services in monit. This way I can focus on one format and I can share service configs across any distros.

Comment: Check the syntax with `init-checkconf /etc/init/myscript.conf` ([source](http://askubuntu.com/a/267173/143251))

Comment: @fedorqui says syntax is okay

Comment: How are you running it? I did a little test with what is explained in [How to create a service on Ubuntu Upstart](http://askubuntu.com/a/448536/143251) and worked nicely.

Comment: @fedorqui I've just followed the post you linked and getting the same error. I'm in the /etc/init directory, creating myscript.conf and then running service myscript start.

Comment: Try to run a simple script and see if it works. For example, I created `hello.conf` with content `start on filesystem  //
script //
    date >> /tmp/ddd //
end script` (// are new lines).

Comment: @fedorqui no thats not working - getting the same error - so it must be due to my upstart configuration?

Comment: From your update, see: [vivid - failed to connect to upstart: connection refused](http://askubuntu.com/a/615086/143251)